# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append' python

Tags: python-3.x

I get the error

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'
```

when trying to add the data created in

```
measurements(height,walls)
```

to the dictionary

I want to add this data next to the data that is allready stored under that key.

```
rooms_dict

number = 0
total = 0
room_name_walls = 0
height = 0
width = 0
rooms_dict = {}
print ("welcome to our painting cost estimate calculator")
print ("please enter the following information")

customer_number = input("please enter your telefone number")
date = input("please enter the date of the estimate \n(in short form)")
num_rooms = int(input("please enter the number of rooms that you wish to be painted"))                 


def room_name():
    height = 0
    total = 0
    width = 0
for k in range (num_rooms):
    rooms_dict[input("please enter the name of room {}".format(k+1))]= int(input("how many walls are there in room {}".format(k+1)))
    wallpaper = input("Does room {} need wallpaper removing 9(y/n)".format(k+1))
    if wallpaper == ("y"):
        total = total +70
        print("£70 added to total")
    if wallpaper == ("n"):
        print("no cost added")
    print(rooms_dict)
return measurements(height,width)

def measurements(height,width):
for k,v in rooms_dict.items():
    checker = 0
    while v > checker:
        height = (input("Please enter the height for one wall  in the {}(m)".format(k)))
        rooms_dict[k].append(height)
        width = (input("Now please enter the width for the same wall in the {} (m)".format(k)))
        rooms_dict[k].append(width)
        checker = checker + 1
        print(numrooms)
```

thanks for your help!!!

Comment: `rooms_dict[k]` is an int (The number of people in the room).  What do you expect it to be?  What are you trying to do to that value?

Comment: the k has the key of the dictionary stored under it the key is a string!?!?

Comment: So `k` is a string, but `rooms_dict[k]` is accessing the value stored in `rooms_dict` with key `k`.  That's what this line is doing `rooms_dict[input("please enter the name of room {}".format(k+1))]= int(input("how many walls are there in room {}".format(k+1)))`

Comment: Oh ok thankyou!! So how would I write it so that the code accesses that particular key? As I want to write a new value to it.

Comment: You would do `rooms_dict[k] = height` to replace the value

Comment: i have done as you said above but i still get the same error!!

Comment: `def measurements(height,width):
    for k,v in rooms_dict.items():
        checker = 0
        while v > checker:
            height = (input("Please enter the height for one wall  in the {}(m)".format(k)))
            width = (input("Now please enter the width for the same wall in the {} (m)".format(k)))
            rooms_dict[k].update([v,height,width])
            checker = checker + 1
            print(rooms_dict)`

Comment: `rooms_dict[k]` is an integer.  What would you expect `(4).update([v,height,width])` to do? Do some reading up on dictionaries, especially the syntax surrounding accessing and changing values in them.  http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/dictionaries.html